# Update specific value in an array of key=value pairs in YAML

Tags: yaml, yq

Given the following snippet from a yml file, how can I change the value of MAINTENANCE_MODE to true?

A solution using [mikefarah/yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq) v4.18+ is preferred.

```
web:
  environment:
    - DEBUG=1
    - PORT=8082
    - MAINTENANCE_MODE=false
    - APP_HOME=/opt/app
```

Comment: I hope you are aware of the fact, that you have defined the entries in the `environment` as literal strings i.e. `DEBUG=1` is a literal string as opposed to a YAML key value pair, which would have been of the form `DEBUG: 1`

Comment: A `from_props` function would come in handy.

Comment: @Inian https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#set-environment-variables-in-containers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know that it's in this position, use

```sh
yq -i '.web.environment[2] = "MAINTENANCE_MODE=true"' input.yml
```

If you have to look it up, use

```sh
yq -i '.web.environment[] |= sub("^(MAINTENANCE_MODE=).*$", "${1}true")' input.yml
```

Comment: Its worth adding an explanation so people will understand